# modelling a proportion dependent variable when two teams are involved

Tags: regression, prediction, proportion, beta-regression

I am wondering what the best way to proceed in trying to predict the amount of possession a basketball team gets in a game. I have heard that beta regression tends to be good for proportions, but I am wondering how to go forward since I want the possession of both teams. Obviously possesion of one team will be 1 minus the possession of the other team, but will this always be the output of the regression model if it had the structure:

$$
g(p) = x_i^T\beta
$$

where $p$ is the possession of a single team.

Answer (score 1):

yes, g() is then the link function of your GLM model. Try package betareg, and this paper might help. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf

Comment: but im asking if there are any issues with this approach? Is it problematic if we have our response variables $y_1, y_2$ where there is a dependency $y_1 = 1-y_2$

Comment: Then you can just model y1. Like logistic regression you always predict for P(X=1), and the probability of X=0 just 1-P(X=1).

Comment: How would you construct your model? Do you want to predict for each team, i.e build a model for each team? Or how would you like to do it?